# SQL UPDATE Where Clause ')'

Tags: sql, vb.net

how can I end this SQL UPDATE statement? The debugger is telling me that

> String constants must end with double quote

and is hiighlighting the end of the WHERE Clause `"', con)`

```
  cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonsA SET(Members_ID='" & midtxt.Text & "'Gamer_Tag='" & gttxt.Text & "'Screenname='" & sntxt.Text & "'First_Name='" & fntxt.Text & "'Last_Name='" & lntxt.Text & "'DoB='" & dobtxt.Text & "'E_Mail_Address='" & emailtxt.Text & "'Position='" & teamptxt.Text & "'UG_Studio'" & ugptxt.Text & "'Cautions='" & ugctxt.Text & "'Record='" & recordtxt.Text & "'Event_Attendance='" & eventatxt.Text & "'Members_Status='" & memberstatcombo.Text & "'GTA_V_Crew_Member='" & gtavcrewmembercombo.Text & "'Games_Owned='" & gamesownedtxt.Text & "'Rep_Group='" & RepGroupcombo.Text & "'WHERE Members_ID='" & midtxt.Text & "', con)
```

Comment: Add a double quote after the single quote and also add commas between the items

Comment: If you used a parameterized query this kind of errors are highly improbable.

Comment: Change `"', con)` to `"'", con)` - The syntax higlighting in your question makes it easy to identify

Answer (score 2):

In the end change

```
"', con)
```

with

```
"'", con)
```

And give a try.

Comment: No, still resulted with the same error. But I think it's to do with the structure of it, I'll try @M.Ali's answer, I think that's probably my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Not only you have missed the closing double quote, added a wrong parenthesys before the SET but also your UPDATE syntax is wrong because you miss the comma that should separate the fields.

Switching to a parameterized query will clear a lot of things

```
  cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonsA SET Members_ID=@id, Gamer_Tag=@game, " & _
        "Screenname=@screen, First_Name=@first, Last_Name=@last, DoB=@dob," & _
        "E_Mail_Address=@email, Position=@pos, UG_Studio=@ustudio, Cautions=@caution," & _
        "Record=@record, Event_Attendance=@event, Members_Status=@memstatus, " & _
        "GTA_V_Crew_Member=@gtva, Games_Owned=@gameowned, Rep_Group=@repgroup" & _
        "WHERE Members_ID=@id", con)

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",midtxt.Text)
  .... follow with other parameters ....
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

As you can see, using a parameterized query simplify your command text and remove all that ugly string concatenation where subtle syntax errors are hidden from view.
Of course a parameterized query removes also any possibility of [Sql Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

A simple review about [UPDATE statement](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_update.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though the start did seam a little condescending. I've adopted your method show here and I'm receiving a rather strange error 'Member_Status could not be converted to data type int'. It's text that's in the field and the SQL column is set to varchar(35). Why am I receiving this error when at no point have I told it to treat Member_Status as an integer?

Comment: Sorry to have given this impression, it was not my intention. It is in effect a strange error. Could you add to your question the actual code that use the parameters?

Comment: Also I have just noticed that you marked your question with the MySql tag but then you use SqlCommand that is a class used only for Sql Server.

Comment: Hi, it's difficult to tell people intention in text, my apologize; you're being a great help here! The Server is MS SQL Server ('08 or 05 not sure.) I've created a new question for the error;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223091/my-sql-converting-to-int-when-it-shouldnt-o-o

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonsA SET(Members_ID='" & midtxt.Text &
                               ^ this Parenthesis is not needed
```

Correct Syntax for UPDATE Statement is like

```
 UPDATE PersonsA
  SET Members_ID= SomeValue,
      ColumnName = SomeValue,
      .
      .
      ... and so on...
 WHERE Clause
```

Answer (score 0):

at some point in there you switch from the pattern `'" ... "'` to `"' ... '"`