# My SQL Converting to Int when it shouldn't O.o

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Okay, I'm receiving the following error whilst updating my SQL Record from my program:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar
>   value 'Full Member' to data type int.

Here's the Update code; (I've marked the two spots that refer to the textbox which contains TEXT, but is trying to be converted to INT for no reason.

```
Public Class EditSelected
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim stcon As String
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
```

.

```
Private Sub EditSelected_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
stcon = "{Censored Connection String}"
        con = New SqlConnection(stcon)

        con.Open()


        cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonsA SET Members_ID=@id, Gamer_Tag=@gt, " & _
        "Screenname=@screen, First_Name=@first, Last_Name=@last, DoB=@dob," & _
        "E_Mail_Address=@email, Position=@pos, U_G_Studio=@ustudio, Cautions=@caution," & _
        "Record=@record, Event_Attendance=@event, Member_Status=@memstatus, " & _ '<---ERROR HERE
        "GTA_V_Crew_Member=@gtva, Games_Owned=@gameowned, Rep_Group=@repgroup " & _
        "WHERE Members_ID=@id", con)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", midtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gt", gttxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@screen", sntxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", fntxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", lntxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dobtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", teamptxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ustudio", ugptxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caution", ugctxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@record", recordtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event", eventatxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memstatus", memberstatcombo.Text) '<---ERROR HERE
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gtva", gtavcrewmembercombo.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gameowned", gamesownedtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repgroup", RepGroupcombo.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Data has been saved!")

        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PersonsA", con)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "PersonsA")

        LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.DataMember = "PersonsA"
        LeadersAccessTable.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

        con.Close()
```

My SQL Column 'Member_Status's datatype is `varchar(35)` and is nullable.

What's going on here; why's it trying to convert it to an integer?

{EDIT 1}

I've included a screenshot of the table's columns and their datatypes - Screenshot from SQL Management Studio.

[image: Columns & File Names]

Comment: Hove you tried explicitly setting the parameter datatype instead of AddWithValue?

Comment: My guess is that `Member_Status` is not the problem, and the the string value is being used for an integer column.

Answer (score 0):

Woops, this was down to my other code which populates the fields with the data of the selected index. Turns out the 'Full Member' wasn't actually in the right text box and thus was being sent to one of the INT column. The debugger should have been a little more obvious with that :/ Thanks for your help people!